# How much time do I need to transfer from SIN T2 to T4?

Tags: transit, sin

I know I will be coming through immigration , picking up luggage and taking a shuttle to T4. 3 hours is enough?My flight arrives at 17.50 and Air Asia flight departures at 2050. Is it enough time?

I am asking about Changi Airport in Singapore. It is a change of airlines - flight from Europe to Singapore and flight by Air Asia from Singapore to Penang. Two separate bookings/tickets, but hand luggage only.
Thank you for your help:)

Comment: Three hours for clearing inbound immigration/luggage reclaim plus outbound security in time to arrive at the gate before it closes sounds a bit tight to me, but your question is impossible to answer without knowing which airport you’re talking about.

Comment: Beyond knowing which airport you are talking about, knowing whether your two flights are on the same ticket/booking makes a big difference. Since you mention picking up luggage I would think not, which means you need to drop your luggage before the deadline, and being late means a no show and your booking probably being cancelled without any possible compensation. 3 hours seems to be a very bad idea in these circumstances.

Comment: To the 2 people that voted to close AFTER the question was updated to include the missing information - WHY?!? Please leave a comment stating what information you believe is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that you are able to check-in online for your onward flight, and given that you do not have checked luggage you should NOT need to clear immigration, although you will need to go through security.

There is an airside bus that runs from Terminal 2, gate 51 to Terminal 4.  The bus runs every 15-30 minutes, and takes around 12 minutes.  In order to catch this bus you will require a boarding pass for your flight from T4.

Presuming your inbound flight is on time you will have no problems getting between flights in 3 hours.  Of course if your inbound flight is delayed then it could be a different story.

For completeness, if you did have checked bags then you would NOT be able to take this bus - unless your bags had been checked through to the final destination (which they would not be on a flight connecting to AirAsia).  In that case you would need to clear immigration in T2, collect your bags, catch the land-side bus from T2 to T4, check your bags with AirAsia, go through security and immigration (in that order - T4 is different to the other terminals at SIN where it's reversed), and then go to your gate.   This should be doable in 3 hours, but will be much tighter than without checked bags - and if your inbound flight is delayed would become a problem much quicker!

If you were not able to check-in online for your AirAsia flight (but still had no bags) the it would be the same path as above, only obviously without the need to collect bags.

Comment: AirAsia does not have airside check-in available at Changi; so if they can't check in online then they must go through immigration.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, that is exactly what I said.